# Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have came across with the following issue.
    passing the string post to the SecondVC.m

```
FirstVC.m
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"page=1&country=%@&state=%@&city=%@&empId=%@",_WSConstCountryID,_WSConstStateID,_WSConstStateID,_WSConstCityID,EmpId,@"0"];

NSLog(@"%@",post);

SecondVC *second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];

second.advstr = post;
//advstr is a string in SecondVC.m
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];



Error
reason: '-[UINavigationController setAdvstr:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance


when i degub and check

po second.advstr
```

error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: can you share log of NSLog(@"%@",post);

Comment: in which your code broken ?

Comment: where you created the `setAdvstr` method

Comment: problem is this line setAdvstr:]: check once in your project you wwre wrongly called

Comment: i think your SecondVC is the navigationController .

Comment: page=1&country=USA&state=Virginia&city=&empId=251    @KKRocks issue with second.advstr = post;

Comment: because you passed arguments are more then its required :     NSString *post = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"page=1&country=%@&state=%@&city=%@&empId=%@",_WSConstCountryID,_WSConstStateID,_WSConstCityID,EmpId];

Comment: remove _WSConstStateID and @"0" from string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you are trying to set a property of `SecondVC` to an instance of `UINavigationController`. Based on your code, it means that the storyboard contains a `UINavigationController` with the identifier "SecondVC", perhaps you have a `SecondVC` controller set as its `rootViewController`.